# Remove part of the string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, replace

I have this value for transaction_date = `"Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"` and I wanted to remove this `GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

I have this following codes:

```
String sNew = transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time", String.Empty);
```

The problem is the value of sNew became null.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: String sNew = transaction_date.text.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time", "");

Comment: I've got an error once I will put .text

Comment: You have a typo - `Peninsule` should be `Peninsula` (other wise, it works fine)

Comment: I was just wrong typing it in here but not in my code.

Comment: The edited code you have shown works fine (although it has a extra space at the end which you probably do not want)

Comment: What will happen when we use  "" in the place of String.Empty . i.e transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)", "");

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. You are missing a closing bracket in the first parameter to the Replace method, should be "GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)".

Comment: Works for me if I use string.Empty or "".

Comment: @Jen143Me, did you get this working?

Comment: Yes, I use substring function

Answer (score 0):

I have just run this on linqpad, and it works OK...

```
string transaction_date = "Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800(Malay Peninsule Standard Time)";

string sNew = transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsule Standard Time)", string.Empty);

Console.Write(sNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have described your problem, I cannot reproduce it.

Looking at the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) for `String.Replace(String, String)`, I cannot see that it would ever return null. If `transaction_date` were null to start with you would get a`NullReferenceException` when calling `Replace`. If it was an empty string you would get an empty string back.

I've tried the following, and each time the result is `Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00`.

```
transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)", string.Empty);
transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)", "");
transaction_date.Replace("GMT+0800(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)", null);
```